# Each row 3 column sum result show as running total in last column, then from 2nd row > first row running total show in first column with group by

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Each row Total value go for the set OP value for the next row, except the first row

My Table Data

| Id | WarehouseId | ProductId | OP | RE | IS | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10000 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 100 | 10000 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 100 | 10000 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 15 |
| 5 | 101 | 10001 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| 6 | 101 | 10001 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 8 | 101 | 10001 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 15 |
| 9 | 101 | 10002 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 25 |
| 10 | 101 | 10002 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| 11 | 101 | 10002 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 15 |

I want to show below result     **(OP+RE)-IS=Total**

| Id | WarehouseId | ProductId | OP | RE | IS | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10000 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 100 | 10000 | 10 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 100 | 10000 | 5 | 15 | 0 | 20 |
| 5 | 101 | 10001 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| 6 | 101 | 10001 | 15 | 0 | 5 | 10 |
| 8 | 101 | 10001 | 10 | 15 | 0 | 25 |
| 9 | 101 | 10002 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 25 |
| 10 | 101 | 10002 | 25 | 0 | 10 | 15 |
| 11 | 101 | 10002 | 15 | 15 | 0 | 30 |

Comment: I really do not understand what is happening.  Please explain, for instance, where "10" and "5" come from in the `OP` column on the second and third rows.

Comment: 1st row Total set as 2nd row OP, 2nd row Total set as 3rd row OP, 3rd row Total set as 4th row OP, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive subquery factoring for that purpose like below. You need to rank your data as you have some gaps between IDs in your data. Column name = IS is not allowed, You should use "IS" enclosed by ".

```sql
with t1 ( ID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, OP, RE, "IS", RNB, rnb_per_wh_prod) as (
    select ID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, OP, RE, "IS"
        , row_number()over(order by WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, ID) rnb
        , row_number()over(partition by WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID order by ID) rnb_per_wh_prod
    from Your_table t
), cte (ID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, OP, RE, "IS", Total, RNB) as (
    select ID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, OP, RE, "IS", OP + RE - "IS", RNB
    from t1
    where rnb_per_wh_prod = 1
union all
    select  t1.ID
            , t1.WAREHOUSEID
            , t1.PRODUCTID
            , case when t1.op = 0 then c.OP + c.RE - c."IS" else t1.OP end as OP
            , t1.RE
            , t1."IS"
            , case when t1.op = 0 then c.OP + c.RE - c."IS" else t1.OP end + t1.RE - t1."IS" total
            , t1.RNB
    from cte c
    join t1 on (t1.RNB = c.RNB + 1 
            and c.WAREHOUSEID = t1.WAREHOUSEID 
            and c.PRODUCTID = t1.PRODUCTID)
)
select ID, WAREHOUSEID, PRODUCTID, OP, RE, "IS", TOTAL
from cte
order by id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, "every 3 row" is a coincidence in your data; in fact, the computation must be done separately for each product in each warehouse, no matter how many rows there are for each distinct combination. And the "id" column is in reality some sort of timestamp - ordering is by "id".

If so, you can do it all in a single query using analytic `sum()`. Instead of creating a table for testing, I included all the sample data in a WITH clause at the top of the query itself; you can remove the WITH clause, and use your actual table and column names. I also changed the column name `is` to `is_` since **is** is a reserved keyword, it can't be a column name.

Note also that I am ignoring your existing `total` column completely (I didn't even include it in the sample data); I assume it doesn't exist in your real-life data, and instead it is part of your attempt at a solution. You don't need it - not in the way you have it in your question.

```
with
  sample_data (id, warehouseid, productid, op, re, is_) as (
    select  1, 100, 10000, 10,  0,  0 from dual union all
    select  2, 100, 10000,  0,  0,  5 from dual union all
    select  4, 100, 10000,  0, 15,  0 from dual union all
    select  5, 101, 10001, 15,  0,  0 from dual union all
    select  6, 101, 10001,  0,  0,  5 from dual union all
    select  8, 101, 10001,  0, 15,  0 from dual union all
    select  9, 101, 10002, 25,  0,  0 from dual union all
    select 10, 101, 10002,  0,  0, 10 from dual union all
    select 11, 101, 10002,  0, 15,  0 from dual
  )
select id, warehouseid, productid,
       nvl(sum(op + re - is_) over (partition by warehouseid, productid
           order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
           op) as op,
       re, is_,
       sum(op + re - is_) over 
          (partition by warehouseid, productid order by id) as total
from   sample_data
;

    ID WAREHOUSEID  PRODUCTID         OP         RE        IS_      TOTAL
------ ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1         100      10000         10          0          0         10
     2         100      10000         10          0          5          5
     4         100      10000          5         15          0         20
     5         101      10001         15          0          0         15
     6         101      10001         15          0          5         10
     8         101      10001         10         15          0         25
     9         101      10002         25          0          0         25
    10         101      10002         25          0         10         15
    11         101      10002         15         15          0         30
```